# how to check the response type(Json/Html) in webview in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I have a web view which request one web page, now that web has some action events which may reply to IOS app as HTML or json. So how would the app will come to know the response type sent. So that the response is handled within the app.

Reading of static HTML content in webview using its delegate is what i have tried, when it is dynamic then how can one handle.

code logic:-

1. ON load of controller, request page with URL(something) in web view, user will interact
2. check response type if JSON then 4 else 3
3. load web page with different URL
4. Deserialize the JSON Data and store in native DB

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

First, You need to set and handle the `UIWebView` delegate methods in your `UIViewController`

Then, in `webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:` method, use the following

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSError *error;
    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:request.URL
                                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                           error:&error];

    //Parse the string here to confirm if it's JSON or HTML
    //In case of JSON, stop the loading of UIWebview
    if(json) {
        retrun NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Note:** This will take a performance hit in case of HTML content as the response will be loaded 2 times. Once in `stringWithContentsOfURL` method and second time when the web view loads.

**Method 2**

To avoid the double loading you can let the web view load, irrespective of the content type. And then get the loaded content in `webViewDidFinishLoad` method.

*For this you may need to perform some changes on the server end as well.*

Suppose your HTML page with JSON is structured as :

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="json" style="display: none">{"jsonvalue":"{{result}}"}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in `webViewDidFinishLoad`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *res = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('json').innerHTML"];

    //Use the JSON string as required
}
```

Comment: The solution you gave is pretty much good. Thank you for that. 
I am thinking to opt the second method to increase the performance.  
I have one question, when the web page is loaded first time then the <div></div> is empty, as soon as the user interacts(clicks) then the div is updated. now  the question is how will I (app) will come to know the user has clicked / any event has occured / data is filled in div Tag .?
Hope my question is clear to you.  In case not then kindly let me know.

Comment: As I understand, the `div` tag will update when the `UIWebView` 's content is updated. In this case, you will receive a call back to `webViewDidFinishLoad` method. You can simply check the `res` string's length to determine if you received any data from the mentioned tag *id*.

Comment: I have accepted your solution. Thank you.
there is one thing to share, one of my old colleague has given another method(3). That is - web server can call a method within the app by setting the URL by method name and parameters. On which I am working whichever fits good with performance I would continue with it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

After the long brainstorming as i am new to IOS, I figure out the solution for swift as I could not find the solution in swift language. Here are the few steps for solutions-

1. First drag and drop the webView to create the connection of webview

   *@IBOutlet weak var webViewlLoad: UIWebView!*
2. Now load your webView by calling

   *webViewlLoad.loadRequest(URL)*
3. Now wait for some time and check the webview for getting the data by the following code

> ```
>     let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 5 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
>
>     dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
>
>  //put your code which should be executed with a delay here
>
>      let doc = self.webViewlLoad.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.outerHTML")!
>
>     print("document JSON  = \(doc)")
>
>     let startIndexJSON  = doc.rangeOfString("{")?.startIndex
>
>     let endIndexJSON  = doc.rangeOfString("}}")?.startIndex
>
>     var finalJson =   doc.substringWithRange( Range<String.Index>(start:startIndexJSON!, end: endIndexJSON!.advancedBy(2)))     
>     print("\n\n finalJson JSON  = \(finalJson)")
>
>   }
> ```

In above code i wait for 5 seconds , then the webView load the json. I read it by substring the result.